# Convert serial number to character representation in R

Tags: r, date

I am importing some weather data, but the timestamp is split across different columns. I want to join these columns and create posix objects out of them.

```
datenum <- c()
for (i in 1:dim(weather)[1]){

date_string <- paste0(weather$Year.UTC[i],'-',weather$Month.UTC[i],'-',weather$Day.UTC[i],'-',weather$Hour.UTC[i]) # different columns of data
# for i = 1, date_string = "2012-12-31-23"

datenum[i] <- as.POSIXct(date_string, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H",tz="GMT", origin = "1960-01-01")
# for i = 1, datenum[1] = 1356994800 (numeric)
}

as.Date(datenum[1], origin = "1960-01-01")
# Gives character = "7285-07-27"
```

To visually confirm that I am doing it right, I would like to see a string in the form "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS", which is what I try to obtain with as.Date. The origin is the same when converting to a serial number and back to a character, but the date is completely wrong. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
weather <- data.frame(Year.UTC=c(2012, 2013), 
                      Month.UTC=c(1,2), 
                      Day.UTC=c(1,2),
                      Hour.UTC=c(22,23))
weather <- within(weather, datetime <- 
              as.POSIXct(paste(Year.UTC, Month.UTC, Day.UTC, Hour.UTC, sep="-"),
                         format="%Y-%m-%d-%H", tz="UTC"))

#  Year.UTC Month.UTC Day.UTC Hour.UTC            datetime
#1     2012         1       1       22 2012-01-01 22:00:00
#2     2013         2       2       23 2013-02-02 23:00:00
```

As you see, you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: Thanks Roland. That works fine. I did not know about the within function. I still find it curious that my example gives an erroneous output with the same origin.

Comment: The reason is that `POSIXct` is represented as seconds internally and `Date` as days.